# Ordenamiento burbuja con tipo genérico T

Tags: java, genéricos

Tengo el siguiente método para ordenar por método de la burbuja, y quisiera que, en vez de recibir un arreglo de enteros, reciba un arreglo de `T`. ¿Cómo hago el arreglo `T`? El arreglo que se recibe es un arreglo de cualquier tamaño.

```
public void burbuja(int[]v){
    int superior,temp;
    boolean bandera=true;
    superior=v.length;
    while(bandera){
        bandera=false;
        superior--;
        for(int i=0; i<superior;i++){
            if(v[i]>v[i+1]){
                temp=v[i];v[i]=v[i+1];v[i+1]=temp;
                bandera=true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Antes de poder convertir el método como lo deseas, debes tomar en cuenta 2 limitaciones con los genéricos en Java:

1. Los genéricos en Java solo pueden manejar objetos, no los tipos primitivos como `int`. De modo que al convertir tu método para que sea genérico, ya no podrás pasarle un arreglo de `int`. Pero sí podrás usar un arreglo de `Integer` por ejemplo, porque un `Integer` es un objeto.
2. Ya que los genéricos en Java solo pueden manejar objetos, quiere decir que no puedes usar el operador `>` como lo haces en la línea siguiente:

   ```
   if(v[i]>v[i+1]){
   ```

   Mas bien, lo más recomendable sería que uses el interfaz [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) y que exijas que el tipo genérico implemente ese interfaz.

Con esto en mente, el método se puede definir de la forma siguiente:

```
public <T extends Comparable<T>> void burbuja(T[] v) {
    boolean bandera = true;
    int superior = v.length;
    while (bandera) {
        bandera = false;
        superior--;
        for (int i = 0; i < superior; i++) {
            if (v[i].compareTo(v[i + 1]) > 0) {
                T temp = v[i];
                v[i] = v[i + 1];
                v[i + 1] = temp;
                bandera = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Con este método, puedes usar arreglos de cualquier tipo `T`, siempre y cuando `T` implemente el interfaz [`Comparable<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). Esto incluye todos los tipos básicos como `Integer`, `String`, etc... y siempre puedes definir tus propias clases que implementen la interfaz.

Ejemplo de cómo usarlo con diferentes tipos:

```
Integer[] intArray = new Integer[]{7, 4, 9, 2, 6, 10};
burbuja(intArray);

System.out.println("Lista ordenada de enteros:");
for (int i : intArray) {
    System.out.println(i);
}

System.out.println();
String[] stringArray = new String[]{"suelo", "cielo", "piso", "piedra", "adentro"};
burbuja(stringArray);

System.out.println("Lista ordenada de cadenas:");
for (String s : stringArray) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

[**Demostración en vivo**](http://rextester.com/HALDY42346)

Comment: Hice un ajuste al enlace de la demostración para que puedas ver como puedes usar el método `burbuja` (no estático) desde el `main`. Pero es solo cuestión de crear una instancia de la clase que contiene el método `burbuja` y ejecutar el método usando esa instancia. Pero esos son detalles menores que puedes ajustar según lo necesites.

Comment: claro que sí...

Comment: Si entiendo lo que dices, eso ya no es un uso correcto de genéricos y viene siendo una pregunta distinta. Con un tipo genérico, puedes pasarle arreglos de cualquier tipo, pero cada arreglo debe ser de un tipo solamente. Si deseas un arreglo con una mezcla de tipos, entonces en vez de genéricos, probablemente tendrías que usar un arreglo de tipo `Object`. Pero si haces eso, no es claro como quieres que se ordene el arreglo. Tendrías que definir la lógica para comparar objetos de diferentes tipos mezclados. Esto no suena práctico.